# Magento 1.9 - Share/copy wishlist between customers

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist

Are there any ways to copy a customers wishlist, and then import it into another customers wishlist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default magento has the share wishlist feature. The customers can share the wishlist from wishlist page.

The below link will helps you to import the wishlist

https://mobecls.com/importing-wishlists-magento-store-step-step/